# taking an image of two partitions without unallocated space

Tags: linux, partitioning, usb-storage, disk-image

I have a 32GB SD card with 1GB FAT32 on sdc1, 10GB EXT4 on sdc2 and 21GB unallocated space. I want to get a single disk image file that would contain sdc1 and sdc2. So the image would be of an 11GB total space. How can I create a disk image of such a disc on ubuntu or windows or whatever?

Note: i tried using win32DiskImager with read only allocated partitions but it still read the whole storage. I cant figure out the reason of this behavior.

Comment: Why not just create two images of the partitions + an MBR backup?

Comment: ok so if i took an image of each partition by ubuntu using dd command for both partitions then how do i do this MBR backup so these two would be on a single image file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using some other Disk Image utility. One examples is **Macrium Reflect Free**, which doesn't include the Unallocated space into the Image (and you can also select any partition of the disk you do not want to include.)

Download **Macrium Reflect Free** from https://updates.macrium.com/reflect/v8/ReflectDLHF.exe

Comment: awesome app! definetly solved the issue.